# Apple Mach-O Linker Error id: file not found -fobjc-link-runtime clang

Tags: ios

I have never come across this error before, can anyone tell me how I go about fixing it.
I get this error on simulation and ios device run.

```
ld: file not found: -fobjc-link-runtime
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


(null): File not found: -fobjc-link-runtime

(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Do you have a .pch file?

Comment: What is the full command line for ld?